# Trying to change a loop to a recursive method. Having some toruble

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I need to include recursion into my final project. It was recommended to me to simply change one of my loops to a recursive method. Here's what I have so far. It returning a value of 0 every time.

```
public static double GetCostTotal(Liquor[] inv, int index)  {
        if ( index >= inv.length) return 0;
        else return GetCostTotal(inv, index + 1);
}
```

Here's where I call it in my main method:

```
//beer. regular 1d array 
        System.out.println("\nNow for beer. How many beers are you taking inventory of?: ");
        int sizeBeers = keyboard.nextInt();
        Beer[] invBeers = new Beer[sizeBeers];        
        for (int i = 0; i < invBeers.length; i++)   {
            invBeers [i] = new Beer();
            System.out.println("Enter product name: ");
            invBeers [i].setLiquorName(keyboard.next());
            System.out.println("Enter the count: ");
            invBeers [i].setLiquorCount(keyboard.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("Enter the cost: ");
            invBeers [i].setLiquorCost(keyboard.nextDouble());
        }        
        //calls GetCostTotal method and passes invBeers array 
        double beerCost = GetCostTotal(invBeers, sizeBeers);
        System.out.println("The total cost of the beer inventory is: $" + beerCost);
```

I'm still trying to find my own solution but obviously looking for some help from you guys too. Thanks!

Comment: What do you *want* this to do?

Comment: If you want to calculate the cost of beer recursively, you need to return the CUMULATIVE sum of the cost. It looks like you are going to return zero no matter what you do.

Comment: Also, is `Beer` inheriting from `Liquor`? If not,  your method is not going to work for `Beer`.

Comment: yeah sorry I could have clarified that. Trying to add the total cost of the beer inventory (beerCount * beerCost).

Comment: And do you see that you are not performing that calculation anywhere? That's your problem. Your base case need to return the cumulative sum, and your recursive call need to calculate and accumulate.

Comment: @RedBassett You are correct. This is not a good candidate for recursion. BUT, that's not the point here. The OP wants to convert the code which I believe is a good exercise regardless of its practicality in real life.

Comment: Your recursive call cannot overwrite your cumulative sum. So... you might want to consider passing that as a parameter as well.

Comment: beer is inheriting from liquor, yes. I realize now that I'm not actually calculating anywhere.  Trying to fix it now. will update in a bit. thank you

Comment: @hfontanez This is a good enough candidate for recursion. There's no need for an accumulator unless you want to write the recursive call in tail position, but Java doesn't optimize tail calls, so it doesn't really help.

Comment: By the way, I know this is just an assignment, but you should never use `double` for monetary values. Either use an integral type and represent money as a whole number of cents, or use a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: good to know, I'm still 100% in the intro to Java phase so tips like those are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidConrad I think this case is too trivial for recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive method should be something like this:

```
public static double GetCostTotal(Liquor[] inv, int index, double total) {
    if (index >= inv.length)
        return total;
    else
        total = inv[index].amount() * inv[index].cost();
        return GetCostTotal(inv, index + 1, total);
}
```

You can see that `total` is a parameter passed to the function so that you could effectively accumulate the sum of the costs. Otherwise, you will overwrite the amount with each call. Second, the `else` clause is performing the necessary calculation.

Lastly, your initial call was triggering the default (base) case because you were passing the length of the array instead of starting at zero.

```
    double beerCost = GetCostTotal(invBeers, 0, 0);
```

Since your recursive call is incrementing `index` by one, you need to pass zero for the `index` and zero for the `total`.

If you do this, you should get the right result. This is my sample input and result:

```
Now for beer. How many beers are you taking inventory of?: 
3
Enter product name: 
Bud
Enter the count: 
1
Enter the cost: 
2
Enter product name: 
Miller
Enter the count: 
2
Enter the cost: 
3
Enter product name: 
Michelob
Enter the count: 
3
Enter the cost: 
4
The total cost of the beer inventory is: $20.0
```

You can see that for the first iteration the cumulative cost is 2.00 (1*2), for the second is 6.00 (2*3), and for the last is 12.00 (3*4), which totals 20.00 (2 + 6 + 12)

**NOTE**: I created a Java record for `Beer` instead of a conventional class. That's why the methods I am calling in `GetCostTotal` are `cost()` and `amount()`. You will need to change them to match your correct method names OR change `Liquor` and `Beer` to be Java records which I HIGHLY recommend if you are using the latest Java.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just add the total cost of the current item and the result of the recursive call:

```
public static double GetCostTotal(Liquor[] inv, int index)  {
        if (index >= inv.length) return 0;
        else return (inv.getLiquorCount() * inv.getLiquorCost()) + GetCostTotal(inv, index + 1);
}
```

Note: this is not tail recursive, and, anyway, Java doesn't optimize tail calls, so if your array is too long, you'll get a StackOverflowError.

If you modify it to use an accumulator, as in hfontanez's answer, and write it in a language and on a platform that does proper tail call elimination, it will not overflow. Hopefully one day Java will add TCO/TCE.

Answer (score 0):

Solution here. Wasn't performing necessary calculations and was calling the method incorrectly.

```
public static double GetCostTotal(Liquor[] inv, int index, double totalCost)  {
        if ( index >= inv.length) return totalCost;
        else totalCost = inv[index].getLiquorCount()*inv[index].getLiquorCost();
        return GetCostTotal(inv, index + 1, totalCost);
    }

double beerCost = GetCostTotal(invBeers, 0, 0);
        System.out.println("The total cost of the beer inventory is: $" + beerCost);
```